# Website not available unless www is in front of the url in Chrome browser are there any tricks to fix this?

Tags: browser, web, google-chrome

My website is accessible without www in the front of it in Firefox and Safari however for some reason it is not in Chrome. Is there anything that I need to change on my website host or in the html to make it accessible?

Comment: You should post a link. I suspect it may be a Chrome configuration problem if anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your website is not already set up to do so, you'll need to update your web host to respect requests for `http://your-website.com` as well as `http://www.your-website.com`.

Firefox (and apparently Safari) will make a **second** request to a URL using or removing the `www.` in front of it if they receive a 404 error before displaying any resulting errors to the user. (And if the alternate URL works they will display the results of the second request and silently drop the results of the first [the 404 error].)  Most, if not all other browsers will just display the first 404 error page.

What web server are you running on?

Comment: Nice factoid. Didn't know this one. :)

Comment: Currently using homestead.com, also thanks for the quick response